# Detect iPhone/iPad purely by css

Tags: iphone, css, ipad

I've been trying to detect an iPhone or iPad purely by stylesheet. I tried the solution provided [here](http://iphone.wikidot.com/detection) by using @media handheld, only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {.

However, this doesnt seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Related newer question: [CSS media query to target only iOS devices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30102792/3345375)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is how I handle iPhone (and similar) devices [not iPad]:

In my CSS file:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px), only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
   /* CSS overrides for mobile here */
}
```

In the head of my HTML document:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
```

Comment: Is there non media-query way to do this? Since iPad Safari has this bug-feature where it re-sizes the big background pictures to 50% and this bug-feature does not exist on other small-pixel browsers. So one needs something like IE conditionals for iPad? So I could target only the iPad/iPhone safari?

Comment: Don't use this, [never set `user-scalable=no`](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201106/the_ios_zoom_setting_disables_maximum-scale1_and_user-scalableno/)

Comment: I have to agree with bfred.it here. `user-scaleable=no` is not a good practice.

Comment: I disagree on the "never" part for user-scaleable. If you're building a native-like responsive web app, having it user scaleable can only cause problems. If you designed it correctly, there shouldn't ever be a need for a user to wish to zoom in/out.

Comment: @Vexter you are correct, this is a good use case for this attribute. But it is clearly incorrect in the context of the original question and answer.

Comment: I totally agree with Vexter. It's exactly my current situation. "Never" was just not the right word

Answer (score 32):

iPhone & iPod touch:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="../iphone.css" type="text/css" />
```

iPhone 4 & iPod touch 4G:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" type="text/css" href="../iphone4.css" />
```

iPad:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px)" href="../ipad.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: The iPad detection has a problem: be ready that netbooks that usually have screens 1024x768 and 1024x600 will be affected by this CSS too.

Comment: [Never detect specific devices](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12990647/288906). New devices come out every month and these numbers change.

Answer (score 21):

I use these:

```
/* Non-Retina */
@media screen and (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
}

/* Retina */
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
}

/* iPhone Portrait */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation:portrait) {
} 

/* iPhone Landscape */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation:landscape) {
}

/* iPad Portrait */
@media screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait) {
}

/* iPad Landscape */
@media screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape) {
}
```

http://zsprawl.com/iOS/2012/03/css-for-iphone-ipad-and-retina-displays/

Comment: Added " and (max-device-width: 1024px)" condition for iPad.

Comment: What happens if you have an Android device that has a width of 460px?

Comment: it helped me identify iPad for ionic angularjs app

Answer (score 16):

You might want to try the solution from [this O'Reilly article](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/04/using-css-media-queries-ipad.html).

The important part are these CSS media queries:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="iphone.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait)" href="ipad-portrait.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape)" href="ipad-landscape.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (min-device-width: 1025px)" href="ipad-landscape.css">
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: Thanks for pointing that out, have updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Many devices with different screen sizes/ratios/resolutions have come out even in the last five years, including new types of iPhones and iPads. It would be very difficult to customize a website for each device.

Meanwhile, media queries for `device-width`, `device-height`, and `device-aspect-ratio` have been deprecated, so they may not work in future browser versions. (Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media#Media_features))

TLDR: Design based on browser widths, not devices. [Here's a good introduction to this topic](http://verekia.com/initializr/responsive-template/).

Comment: Device-specific queries are required to workaround device-specific bugs.

Comment: I want to use specific graphics (Mail.app icon) if the page is being displayed on an iPhone.