# Direct the website to the Ipad with new css suitable for Ipad

Tags: asp.net, html, css, ipad, web

I have website with two css flies the first one to view the site in a desktop screen the second one to view it in Ipad screen , Knowing that they have the same HTML code  ,, 

my Q : is there any code to detect the Ipad and force to take the css file that is suitable for it??

thxx

edited section:
dears thxxx for the answer but css effect no longer appear, I think I code something wrong, what I have done is :

in the main page at the header I add thess lines:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=980" /><br/>
<link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

inside the site.css I code:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 

{
*
    {
        margin::0;
        padding:0;
    }
    html , body
    {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        width:100%;
        font-family:"Trebuchet MS";
        font-size:12px;

    }
    .Wrapper{margin:0 auto;}

    .InnerWrapper{width:100%;
        margin:0; 
        padding-top:140px; 
        float:none; 
        display:block; 
        height:auto;}

    .Header{padding-bottom:0; 
        height:140px;
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
        z-index: 100000;
        position: fixed;
        color: #000000;
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
        box-shadow:0 -1px 7px 5px #888888;}
}
```

but this not work ... can you help please !!

Comment: have you try using css @media and <meta name="viewport" ... ?

Comment: already add this in the header <meta name="viewport" content="width=980" /> ,, but not tried Media query

Comment: Both Kev and ricardohdz's solutions are valid - a huge advantage of using media queries rather than User Agent string is that the styles can then be used by Android or Windows 8 tablets with the same or similar resolutions. For this to be most effective use flexible layouts with relative units (such as percent) where-ever possible.

Comment: My 2 cents here. I always find it wrong that people are talking about supporting iPad, iPhone, etc, when the right approach will be to research how to support different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add this line of code in my asp.net Solution at `<header>` area:

```
   <% if (Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("ipad"))
    { %>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/siteIpad.css" />

    <% } %>
```

it's work fine,,,,

Answer (score 1):

You can use media queries for that. Just put below CSS code at the top of your iPad file and inside all the styles related to that device:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Put your iPad styles here (this covers portrait and landscape modes) */
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Put your iPad styles here (this covers landscape mode)*/
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Put your iPad styles here (this covers portrait mode)*/
}
```

What the media queries do is they check for the device width to identify if its an iPhone, iPad or any other mobile device. For more info just google "media queries".

Comment: dear thxxx for the answer but css effect no longer appear, I think I code something wrong, what I have done is :

in the main page at the header I add thess lines:
<meta name="viewport" content="width=980" />
<link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

Comment: Try reducing the viewport on your screen. DO that by resizing the window and see of the styles come up.

Answer (score 1):

Use media queries to determine screen size.

Phone & iPod touch:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="../iphone.css" type="text/css" />
```

iPhone 4 & iPod touch 4G:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" type="text/css" href="../iphone4.css" />
```

iPad:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px)" href="../ipad.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: thxxx for the answer but the css effect no longer appear I don't know why !!,,

Answer (score 0):

Best way for that are mediaqueries:

[Detect iPhone/iPad purely by css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839809/detect-iphone-ipad-purely-by-css)

[Load css file for ipad only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4880603/load-css-file-for-ipad-only)

Or detect with JS or PHP the USER-AGENT.