# ads and media devices

Tags: css

On my webpage, I have four columns and I'm normal computers the advertising looks good but when I go on my iPhone and makes certain columns bigger and squeezes the others in. Does anybody know how to keep the columns the same size on mobile devices. The page is mainly HTML.

Comment: Please post some of your code- it will make it much easier for people to help you. Posting a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is usually very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

turn of your `scale`. You can use this in your html:

```
<meta name = "viewport" content = "initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = no">
```

here is more info about this:

[http://developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html)

update:

yes there is different way to change design depends of the design.

for example 1 way to do is:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="iPhone.css">
```

so this css is going to take just your mobile, so do different design stylesheet for this .

same thing is :

```
@media handheld, only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    /* overrides or style additions for iPhone */
}
```

in case you do not want to create a new stylesheet.css , let say you want to change 1,2 classes.

but the idea re the same.

There is the JS ways and anthers depends what is you project app do and build on

google knows all these stuff.

here is a post what can be useful for you :

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839809/detect-iphone-ipad-purely-by-css
```

Comment: I tried that but it didnt work and made the page not as nice on phone.  If i use long vertical columns it looks okbut if i try to use Square ads it makes colmuns bad. Is the a way to show one ad if mobile and another ad if computer?