# Mobile Safari rendering CSS differently - any fix?

Tags: html, css, mobile, safari

I have a two column layout (data on left and nav on right). Renders correctly on Safari desktop but Safari for iPhone the right column is rendered at the bottom of the page underneath the data.
The basic code template is:

```
<body>
  <div class="colmask rightmenu">
    <div class="colleft">
      <div class="col1">
        <!-- Column 1 start -->
        <div class="ui-body ui-body-e">
          <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-theme="e" data-content-theme="b">
            some data here
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Column 1 end -->
      </div>
      <div class="col2">
        <!-- Column 2 start -->
          <div class="ui-body ui-body-b">
            nav stuff here
          </div>
        <!-- Column 2 end -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Problem is the same whatever the viewport width is set at (currently 100&%)

Here is the CSS:

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    width:100%;
    background:#fff;
    font-size:90%;
}

a {
  color:#369;
}

a:hover {
  color:#fff;
  background:#369;
  text-decoration:none;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
  margin:.8em 0 .2em 0;
  padding:0;
}

p {
  margin:.4em 0 .8em 0;
  padding:0;
}

img {
  margin:10px 0 5px;
}

#ads img {
    display:block;
    padding-top:10px;
}

/* Header styles */
#header {
  clear:both;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
}

#header {
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}

#header p,
#header h1,
#header h2 {
  padding:.4em 15px 0 15px;
  margin:0;
}

#header ul {
  clear:left;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  list-style:none;
  margin:10px 0 0 0;
  padding:0;
}

#header ul li {
  display:inline;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

#header ul li a {
  display:block;
  float:left;
  margin:0 0 0 1px;
  padding:3px 10px;
  text-align:center;
  background:#eee;
  color:#000;
  text-decoration:none;
  position:relative;
  left:15px;
  line-height:1.3em;
}

#header ul li a:hover {
  background:#369;
  color:#fff;
}

#header ul li a.active,
#header ul li a.active:hover {
  color:#fff;
  background:#000;
  font-weight:bold;
}

#header ul li a span {
  display:block;
}

/* 'widths' sub menu */
#layoutdims {
  clear:both;
  background:#eee;
  border-top:4px solid #000;
  margin:0;
  padding:6px 15px !important;
  text-align:right;
}

/* column container */
.colmask {
  position:relative;    /* This fixes the IE7 overflow hidden bug */
  clear:both;
  float:left;
  width:100%;           /* width of whole page */
  overflow:hidden;      /* This chops off any overhanging divs */
}

/* common column settings */
.colright,
.colmid,
.colleft {
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
}

.col1,
.col2,
.col3 {
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  padding:0 0 1em 0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

/* 2 Column (right menu) settings */
.rightmenu {
  background:#eee;      /* right column background colour */
}

.rightmenu .colleft {
  right:25%;            /* right column width */
  background:#fff;      /* left column background colour */
}

.rightmenu .col1 {
  width:71%;            
  left:27%;         /* (right column width) plus (left column left padding) */
}

.rightmenu .col2 {
  width:21%;            
  left:31%;         
}

/* Footer styles */
#footer {
  clear:both;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  border-top:1px solid #000;
}

#footer p {
  padding:10px;
  margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you may be having an issue with this is because the iPhone and iTouch compared to the computer has a different resolution setting than a generic computer.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPod_Touch

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone

If you don't set up your template to recognize specifics such as mobile computers, or monitor resolutions, you will never get your CSS to render correctly for the screen you are viewing at the time.

Even though you have it set at 100%, you have different settings in your CSS that an iphone, or iTouch may not recognize as well, so you may want to look into that.

I've been working on creating something that is both computer and iPhone/iTouch friendly, and it is not easy.  You'll spend 10 minutes writing the script, 30 min to two days perfecting it.

You may want to look into this:

[Detect iPhone/iPad purely by css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839809/detect-iphone-ipad-purely-by-css)