# Which devices/recommended sizes should I target with mediaqueries?

Tags: css, media-queries

I am new to responsive web design, and got confused because there are various preferences about which media queries to use and which devices to target. Is there a standard?  I'd like to target iPhone, iPads, and other popular devices.

I have found this on the web:

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 and high pixel ratio devices ----------- */
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* Styles */
}
```

But I do not know if it is outdated. I do not know which rule targets iPhone 4, because I ran the iPhone simulator and the CSS didn't work (referring to last CSS rule).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My thought with media queries is that your goal should be to make a device-agnostic framework for your website.  That means it needs to be both resolution and pixel density aware, given Apple's (and others) push into super high resolution screens.

**2018 update**: my approach now drops the `screen` and `min-device-pixel-ratio` media attributes and uses screen-size ranges. Because every device now registers as `screen`, and almost all of them are high resolution now - you really don't need those attributes. If you're on a super high traffic site maybe they still make sense though.

Here is how I lay out my breakpoints globally:

```
/* Below 380px is really just the iPhone SE at this point */

@media (min-width: 380px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  /* Most phones fall in here - iPhone, Galaxy, Pixel, etc */
}

@media (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 768px) { 
  /* Phablets and Tablets - iPad, Galaxy Note, Pixel Slate, Fire */
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 980px) { 
  /* Small desktop, large tablet - Macbooks, sub 12" ultrabooks */
}

@media (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1200px) { 
  /* Medium screen desktop (up to about 24") and laptops (13" laptops) */
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1600px) {
  /* Large screen desktop (27"), laptops (15+") */
}

@media (min-width: 1600px) { 
  /* Very large screen, 4K desktop + small TVs */
}
```

**2012 advice**: I've seen on achieving that dual mandate comes from Chris Coyier's CSS-tricks.com:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/

The concept is to create the initial break points based on size and then have pixel-density media queries follow.  This approach gives you three breakpoints, and each breakpoint has a pixel-density-aware option.

Here is Coyier's sample code (I simplified out the vendor-specific prefixes so you can grasp the concept):

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {
  /* Small screen, non-retina */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (min-width: 320px) { 
  /* Small screen, retina, stuff to override above media query */
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  /* Medium screen, non-retina */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (min-width: 700px) {
  /* Medium screen, retina, stuff to override above media query */
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1300px) {
  /* Large screen, non-retina */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (min-width: 1300px){ 
  /* Large screen, retina, stuff to override above media query */
}
```

I really like this concept: you save bandwidth for older, likely bandwidth constrained devices while giving the new, high-res devices what they need.  The only code you would have to put in the pixel-density media queries should be background-image stuff, so the higher-res imagery overrides its pixelated counterpart on older devices.

Realize that you are trying to hit a moving target my friend ;)  This is an evolving concept, css-tricks.com, stackoverflow and other blogs seem to be the best way to keep up.  Good luck.

Comment: I am not an HTML / CSS man, but I am making a quick site. Would you use this approach still, or do you have any better links? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul - the mechanics are still very similar, but the breakpoints I typically use have changed as screen sizes have evolved. See updated answer.

Comment: Great, thanks! Will read as soon as I can. I am struggling with new issue relating to [Chrome and the new warnings about unsafe connections](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/avoid-not-secure-warn) now - but that is unrelated.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul - just updated the post, see if it helps

Comment: @SteinÅsmul - find a hosting provider that uses https://letsencrypt.org/ - free, secure certificates. You can install them manually but providers like Netlify, Dreamhost, and many others gives you free SSL/TLS now. Take advantage of it.

Comment: Will investigate. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The "breakpoints" in your layout are likely to become quickly outdated as new devices with different viewport ratios come on the market. Perhaps rather than target specific devices, I prefer the approach of having breakpoints in your design where you want it to break, rather than bending your design to specific devices.

This article: [Device-Agnostic Approach To Responsive Web Design](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/22/device-agnostic-approach-to-responsive-web-design/) explains it better than I could ever do.

Alternatively, you could refer to some of the most popular frameworks like [320 and Up](https://github.com/malarkey/320andup) or [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) - they are updated very often and should provide you with a good starting point with media query breakpoints.