# CSS detect either iphone ipad or any other handheld

Tags: css

maybe this is simple but I havent found the answer yet

How do I detect either iphone, ipad, ipad, android phone in any mode via CSS?

I read this
[Detect iPhone/iPad purely by css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839809/detect-iphone-ipad-purely-by-css)
that describes how to detect all the *specific* devices

But what I am looking for is to distinguish between desktop/laptop AND all ipad/ipod/iphone/android devices in general

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are my notes on the matter: For any device - do your research on it's screen sizes and ratios and then do a @media query in your stylesheet for each device.

**iPhone4**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" type="text/css" href="iphone4.css" />
```

**(portrait or landscape) on the iPad**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:portrait)" href="portrait.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all and (orientation:landscape)" href="landscape.css">
```

**Mobile Phones Portrait**

```
 @media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait){
 /* some CSS here */
 }
```

**Mobile Phones Landscape**

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 640px) and (orientation: landscape){
/* some CSS here */
}
```

**Mobile Phones Portrait or Landscape**

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 640px){
  /* some CSS here */
}
```

**iPhone 4+ Portrait or Landscape**

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* some CSS here */
}
```

**iPhone 5 Only**

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 640px) and (max-device-width: 1136px) and (-    webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {
    /* styles here */
}
```

**iPhone < 5: aspect ratio**

```
@media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 2/3) {}
```

**Tablets Portrait or Landscape**

```
@media screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px){
/* some CSS here */
}
```

**Desktops**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px){
/* some CSS here */
}
```

Styles only between two sizes.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 319px) and (max-width: 1281px){}
```

BTDUBS - Did you know that WordPress has an is_iphone() global built in?

```
global $is_iphone;
if ( $is_iphone ) {
 // do something if $is_iphone is true
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Ben - but I would say that the initial query was related more to : what simple CSS way is there the distinghuis betw mobile device and laptop/desktop

Comment: Only screen sizes from my research my friend! If you come across something else please post it here.

Comment: And many thanks for that!! Seems that the media query "handheld" looked like an option, but nobody implemented it

Answer (score 3):

you could use @media queries to solve your problem, the below maybe something you could try. You can also you device orientation as a setting to target your devices or set your max width like below and then write your css. Hope this helps.

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  .class {
    background: #000;
  }
}
```